# Table-Valued parameter default value or pass inline

Tags: sql, sql-server

See the example below,

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    CD varchar(10) not null
)
GO

INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('TEST')
GO

CREATE TYPE [CdTable] AS TABLE (CD varchar(10));
GO

CREATE FUNCTION TestTbl ( @x varchar(10), @c CdTable READONLY )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT t.CD
    FROM test t
    JOIN @c c ON t.CD = c.CD OR c.CD IS NULL
    WHERE t.CD = @x
GO

DECLARE @tt AS CdTable;
INSERT INTO @tt VALUES ('TEST');
SELECT * FROM TestTbl('TEST', @tt);

DELETE FROM @tt;
INSERT INTO @tt VALUES (NULL);
SELECT * FROM TestTbl('TEST', @tt);
GO

CREATE FUNCTION TestNoTbl ( @x varchar(10) )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT *
    FROM TestTbl(@x, ???? ) --<<<< how do I pass inline @c parameter with only a single row set to NULL
GO
```

I want to figure out a way either to:

> 1. assign a default value to the @c parameter
> 2. pass it inline in an helper function

I find no way to do this. 
Anybody can help?

p.s.: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (or newer)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot assign a default value to `Table Valued parameter`. Instead you can alter the function.

Change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT t.CD
FROM test t
LEFT OUTER JOIN @c c ON t.CD = c.CD 
WHERE t.CD = @x
```

even though the `@c` does not hold any records you will get result based on the @x filter

**Update:** Based on your comments

```
If exists(select 1 from @c)
    SELECT t.CD
    FROM test t
    JOIN @c c ON t.CD = c.CD 
    WHERE t.CD = @x
Else 
    SELECT t.CD
    FROM test t
    WHERE t.CD = @x
```

Comment: Thanks Prdp, but I want either to return the rows joining with @c or as a special case return all the rows.
If I do as you told me, @c will not filter the results anymore.

Comment: Two questions:

1. Is it possible to call TestTbl with an empty table without declaring a new parameter?

2. The query in the function will grow to be very complex, do you think that there is  a solution that avoids code duplication? (avoids writing both queries two times one with the JOIN and one without)

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. As far as I know it is not possible you need to declare a table of `CdTable` type and you have to use it in second parameter

Comment: 2. We can use dynamic query to avoid the duplication but unfortunately we cannot use dynamic query inside user defined function

Comment: Regarding point 1, I am using IF (inline function) because it infers the return table type without declaration (easier sql code mantainance), but AFAIK I can't declare a CdTable variable inside them. Am I wrong?
If no solution to my problem exists to avoid code duplication, either I have to solve this on application layer, or I must define only "complex" function prototypes that require the Table-valued parameter even when it is not needed. I do not like either available approach if this is the case.